# how to use cron job to download file in every 7th day of month

Tags: php, cron

I want to let the user to set the option to generate csv report in every 7th day of month . I have code to generate csv but don't know how to implement it with generating every month automatically.will cron job works for this situation.If so then how to set path to save the report for the user.

Answer (score 1):

Ofc you can do it this way. You have to store the data somewhere and invoke a cron when you need it, which checks the data and then calls the report.

Your cron entry should look something like this:

```
0 0 7 * *  php /your/script/file.php
```

More details and a good explanation with tutorial examples can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cron is fine. Write a PHP script runnable from CLI, which gets a list of users, generates their reports and saves them somewhere using some naming scheme, for example "$userid-report.csv".

If you have a lot of reports you should probably make 2 scripts - one for generating, one for sending them via email.

Comment: And how to set the path to save the file in the user system

Comment: @user1438708 You can save them anywhere. For example, you can create a directory 'reports' next to your CLI script, set proper permissions, and save reports there.